# Move file to a directory with a given condition using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

First of all, thank you for your help. I have a problem trying to move a file to a directory. I have the next directories: `Animals` `Boat` `Cars`and I want to move the following files `Animals.txt` `Boat.txt` and `Car.txt` I want to do it so if the name of the file matches the name of the directory it moves to it, instead of doing the following code:

```
mv Animals.txt Animals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like all you need is a simple loop and a parameter expansion to derive directory names from file names.

```
for txt in ./*.txt; do
  dir=${txt%.*}
  if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    echo mv "$txt" "$dir"
  fi
done
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 2):

This script will move all `*.txt` files of the current directory into the corresponding directory if such a directory exists.

```
for f in *.txt
do
    # Avoid possible errors or unwanted commands in case there is no match for *.txt
    if [ "$f" != '*.txt' ]
    then
        # strip trailing .txt
        d="${f%.txt}"
        # check if corresponding directory exists
        if [ -d "$d" ]
        then
            mv "$f" "$d"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: `shopt -s nullglob` would probably be better than `[ "$f" != '*.txt' ]`. `*.txt` can't be a sentinel value there, as it is a valid filename as per POSIX.

Comment: @quik1399 There are already comments in the code. For what exactly do you need an explanation?

Comment: Nothing I already understand it thank you fot your help

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer doesn't work as expected, I missed the part about missing directories. The answer given by @oguz-ismail is better.

```
mkdir animals boat cars
touch animals.txt boat.txt cars.txt
for f in *.txt; do mv -v $f ${f/.txt}; done
renamed 'animals.txt' -> 'animals/animals.txt'
renamed 'boat.txt' -> 'boat/boat.txt'
renamed 'cars.txt' -> 'cars/cars.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for the credit. `${f/.txt}` removes the leftmost instance of `.txt` from `f` (try `f=a.txt.b.txt; echo ${f/.txt}` and you'll see). Better use `${f%.txt}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `mmv`, you can do it without a loop in one line (I'm assuming
the directories already exist):

```
mmv '*.txt' '#1'
```

I you wanted to pull the files out of the directories (i.e. reverse the above
process) you would do:

```
mmv '*/*' '#2'
```